# Android - changing margin issue?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, margin

I have one main linear layout which contains dynamically generated linear layouts. I am animating these layouts on ACTION_DOWN. But if i try to change the margin (top or bottom) of one layout, it affects other layouts as well. How to change one layouts margin without affecting others.

Any help would be rally appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
public View getLinearView() {
    ChildLinearLayout linearLayout = new ChildLinearLayout(context);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(500, 500);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    layoutParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText("Hello World");
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    System.out.println("View Added");
    views.add(linearLayout);
    return linearLayout;
}
```

Comment: try to align those layouts to some not changing (static) layouts rather than changing layouts.

Comment: Are you sure you don't set the same `LayoutParams` in all those dynamic generated `LinearLayouts`, making them share the layouts attributes?

Comment: @Luksprog i have updated my question. This is how i added the layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think since you are calling

```
layoutParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
```

for every dynamically generated layout, if you change these values then it will affect every one of your dynamically generated layouts.

Instead you could change your

`getLinearView() method to  getLinearView(int margin_value)`

and every time you call this method for your dynamically generated layout, you could pass in the value you want for that particular layout.

ex:
If I have 5 layouts and I want to set margin of first one to 50 and others to 20 then

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 if(i==0)
  view=getLinearView(50);
 else
  view=getLinearView(20);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not what i was looking for but still i appreciate your efforts. Thanks.